# ORACLE 12C - SELECT query using ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have to get second five (6-10) best salaries records from sorted table using ROWNUM.

Using ROWNUM is necessary.

When I execute query:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS position, name, salary
    FROM (SELECT name, salary
            FROM employees
            ORDER BY salary DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

I get a first 10 best records.

And now when I try execute query:

```
    SELECT ROWNUM AS position, name, salary
        FROM (SELECT name, salary
                FROM employees
                ORDER BY salary DESC)
        WHERE ROWNUM >= 6 AND ROWNUM <= 10;
```

I get a empty table. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I write in queston that using ROWNUM is necessary, because it's
>   academic task.

In such a case use a subquery

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM (
  SELECT name, salary, ROWNUM as my_rownum
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY salary DESC
)
WHERE my_rownum BETWEEN 6 AND 10
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm), `rownum` is evaluated as the rows are fetched.  If you never fetch the first row, you never get to the second.  Hence, no rows are fetched:

> Conditions testing for `ROWNUM` values greater than a positive integer
>   are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM employees
>     WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
> ```

But, more importantly, you are using Oracle 12C.  So, use `fetch first` instead of `rownum`.  This has multiple advantages.  Besides being standard SQL, you don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

And for your second:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I write in queston that using ROWNUM is necessary, because it's academic task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query and try....

`SELECT name,salary from
( SELECT name,salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) as rn 
from employees )
where rn between 6 and 10;`